# Iterate through the same list starting from different points in Python

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, iterable

I want to iterate through the same list from two different starting points.
I can do this way:

```py
for LayerIndex in range(len( layers ) - 1):
    thisLayer = layers[LayerIndex     ]
    nextLayer = layers[LayerIndex + 1 ]
```

But I'm sure it should have an more Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Not really clear to me what you are trying to do here. Does one iterator depend on the other or are they independent? Why do you need two simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can pull the index of the list from an enumeration of that list:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(layers):        
    if(index<(len(layers)-1)):    
        thiseLayer= elem        
        nexteLayer= layers[index+1]
```

The extra `if` here just checks that the next element actually exists.

I'm not sure if this more  "Pythonic" though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but don't forget the second variable (nextLayer) can't overstep the length of the list/tuple.